# Disable Driver Signing: The boot configuration data store could not be opened

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers

I have been trying to disable driver signing for a few days now and cannot find a tutorial that will work.  I have tried both the directions provided [here](http://www.killertechtips.com/2009/05/05/disable-driver-signing-windows-7/) as well as trying to use the dseo13b.exe.  Neither have worked.  When using the command line way I receive the error; "The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The requested system device cannot be found".

**Edit:** Also tried the F8 when windows is booting.  This also did not work.

Any other ways to disable driver signing? Or any ideas what is going wrong?

I am using Windows Ultimate x64

Answer (score 1):

You can do a one dime disable of driver signature enforcement at boot, use the F8 key to get the selection screen at boot time.

Others you can look at, use at your own risk

http://www.ngohq.com/home.php?page=dseo

See "Proj X11: Digitally Signing an Application" on this page
http://samsclass.info/335/335_S09.shtml#projects

See a post by CaptGrrr on this forum
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprohardware/thread/9b6eee60-855d-47cc-9927-acae3fb6f971

Please post if any of these work, or if you find one that does.

.

Comment: I haven't been able to get any of these to work